# How to replace 1st node attribute value in xml using xpath

Tags: xpath, ant, xmltask

In the below XML, need to replace the namespace by using XPath.

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0">
  <child id="1"></child>
  <child id="2"></child>
</application>
```

I tried with

```
/application/@xmlns
```

and

```
/*[local-name()='application']/@[local-name()='xmlns']
```

Both failed to give the desire output. To replace the text, I have used xmltask replace.

```
<xmltask source="${temp.file1}" dest="${temp.file1}">
    <replace path="/application/@xmlns" withText="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0" />
</xmltask>
```

Comment: Can you post your code which you have used for replace?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `xmlns` is not an attribute. You cannot select it with XPath.

A namespace is part of the node name in XML: `<foo xmlns="urn:foo-namespace" />` and `<foo xmlns="urn:bar-namespace" />` are **not** two nodes with the same name and different attributes, they are two nodes with different names and **no** attributes.

If you want to change a namespace, you must construct a completely new node.

XSLT is better-suited to this task:

```
<!-- update-air-ns.xsl -->
<xsl:transform
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:air4="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.0"
    xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="air4:*">
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

This XSLT transformation does two things:

- the first template (identity template) copies nodes recursively, unless there is a better matching template for a given node
- the second template matches elements in the `air4` namespace and constructs new elements that have the same local name but a different namespace. This happens because of the default namespace declaration in the XSLT. The `http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0` namespace is used for all newly constructed elements.

Applied to your input XML, the result is

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/16.0">
  <child id="1"/>
  <child id="2"/>
</application>
```

You can use Ant's xslt task:

```
<xslt in="${temp.file1}" out="${temp.file1}" style="update-air-ns.xsl" />
```

Comment: Can you plz explain the xsl task. i have tried the above snippets since its failed to replace.

Comment: I think it you will need to take a tour to the documentation if you want to know how the `xslt` task works. I have explained why the `xmltask` cannot do what you want and provided a solution that does what you want. *Integrating* the solution is your job.